# Is this PHP imap connection string wrong?

Tags: php, imap

Can someone tell me if there is something wrong with the following code? Or if the problem isn't related to the code.
I seem to be unable to connect to the mailserver and during execution of the code it responds with a `Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.one.com993}INBOX` error in my class file. And a `Notice: Unknown: Host not found (#11001): imap.one.com993 (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0` below the previous error.

```
class email {

    public $server;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $port;
    public $link;
    public $status;

function connect($host, $port, $login, $pass){

        $this->server = $host;
        $this->username = $login;

        $this->link = imap_open("{". $host . $port."}INBOX", $login, $pass);
            if($this->link) {
                $this->status = 'Connected';
        } else {
            $this->error[] = imap_last_error();
            $this->status = 'Not connected';
        }
    }
}
```

Index file:

```
<?php
    $email = new email();

    $email->connect("imap.one.com", "993", "email@address.com", "passwordString");
?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a colon (`:`) between the host and port because you want `{imap.one.com:993}INBOX`, not `{imap.one.com993}INBOX`. Fix it like this:

```
$this->link = imap_open("{". $host . ":" . $port."}INBOX", $login, $pass);
```

See [the documentation for `imap_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php).

Comment: Right..  not sure why I didn't see that. Thanks, now my problem is `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded` and `Notice: Unknown: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)` Do you have any idea where I should look to fix this?

Comment: @Dennis1679 Hard to say. It could be that you're using a bad domain name or the wrong port (depends on your mail server's configuration), or it could be that the inbox in question has a huge number of emails. Because you've solved the problem you initially posted about, you should  accept an answer to this question. Then ask a new question, using the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. You can link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Yes, somehow there is a time-limit for accepting this answer. So I'll accept it in a few moments. I'll post a new question as you suggested.

Comment: Little searching on using google led me to this solution. Adding `/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert` to the connection string seemed to do the trick. Somehow `imap_open()` is a little bit buggy with SSL connections.

Comment: @Dennis1679 Great! Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the colon:

```
imap_open("{". $host .":". $port."}INBOX", $login, $pass);
```

Without it, PHP thinks the host is "imap.one.com993", and that, obviously, fails a DNS check.